# Remove spaces after commas in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, excel-formula

I would like to ask if there is some shortcut/function how to remove all spaces after commas in Google Sheets?
Here is link to a template https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jweedL8iURMfi-CNYDiRQRb0GZO2ji9cyTTTMf6pFk4/edit?usp=sharing.

I have a sheet which contains many data looking like this (more words in one section, separated by commas and there is space after each comma). However, I need the sections without the spaces after commas (e.g. "dog,cat"). I would like to apply it on the whole sheet.

Any suggestions, please?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a formula to do this, try this in cell `C1`:

`=arrayformula(regexreplace(A:B;",\ ";","))`

[image]

So if you wanted a new Sheet `Hárok2` to copy `Hárok1`, you'd add this to cell `A1` on `Hárok2`:

`=arrayformula(regexreplace('Hárok1'!A:Z;",\ ";","))`

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `Edit` then `Find and replace`. Enter `,`  in Find and enter `,` in Replace then go and Replace either one by one or everything in one go.